# .htaccess and Wordpress wp-json

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, wordpress-rest-api

I have a wordpress site and I'm trying to use a redirect in `.htaccess` to only be able to see the full site from certain IP's, and that is working fine.

But I also need for the `wp-json` and all their subqueries to be accessible for anyone and that is what's not working for me.

All this `.htaccess` is really new to me so maybe I'm not applying Rules and/or conditions correctly. This is my current file:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^/landing/index.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-json(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127.0.0.1$
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^201\.156\.173\.245
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^107\.167\.108\.173
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^107\.167\.108\.185
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^107\.167\.108\.184
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^107\.167\.108\.61
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/landing/?(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)?wp-json(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/landing/index.php$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /landing/index.php [R=302,L]

    #RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-json(.*)$
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

For wp-json and all their subqueries to be accessible for anyone, you need to do below changes.

Remove below 6th line of code from your above htaccess code. Because it's blocking access to wp-json queries.

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-json(.*)$

Also you don't need to write below 18th line of code for wp-json 302 redirect, because you want to allow everyone to access wp-json queries.

So remove below 18th line of code,

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)?wp-json(.*)$

After removing both lines, your all users get access to wp-json queries.

Comment: I'd like to see the simplest htaccess file that correctly handles Wordpress API (i.e., the API gets invoked, and returns JSON).  I'm not sure why @R Tech's example works, so it isn't clear how to adapt it.

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for a way to disable Rest API for a user role called 'external_user' (disable wp-json queries.) I have 4 role users on my backend and i need to disable wp-json queries for one of them. Thanks

Comment: @sampaii I think this would be better served by looking at the register_rest_route() documentation, specifically the 'permission_callback' field and not via .htaccess

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/

Answer (score -2):

My problem was apache2 configuration , make sure configuration allow you to use .htaccess

efi,

Comment: Use comments instead of answers for personal opinions